# scons gfortran: remove "/out" from link line

Tags: fortran, gfortran, scons

I have a problem with linking fortran object files in Scons.
Here is the code of scons commands:

```
env = Environment( ENV = os.environ , TARGET_ARCH="x86_64")
env = env.Clone( LINKFLAGS = '', LINK='gfortran', tools = 'gfortran' )
module = env.Object('bin/module.o', source = 'src/module.f90')
main = env.Object('bin/main.o', source = 'src/main.f90')
env.Requires(main, [module])
sources = [module[0], main[0]]
result = env.Program(target = '#release/result', source = sources)
```

Scons is like to give in linking line:

```
gfortran -o release/result.exe bin/main.o bin/module.o
```

But it gives:

```
gfortran /OUT:release/result.exe bin/main.o bin/module.o
```

It leads to an error:

```
gfortran: error: /OUT:release/result.exe: Invalid argument
```

How can I remove "/OUT" from the linking line?

P.S.

Earlier there was one more problem with defaut value of LINKFLAGS. It was "/nologo" and also led to an error:

```
gfortran /nologo /OUT:release/result.exe bin/main.o bin/module.o
gfortran: error: /nologo: No such file or directory
```

I solved it by LINKFLAGS = ' '.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Please tag it instead of the irrelevant [tag:fortran90] tag.

Comment: Windows 8 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TARGET_ARCH only currently affects MSVC/MSVS.
So you can ommit that.

Also on win32 it's going to default to MSVC toolchain unless you explicitly state otherwise perhaps as follows

```
env = Environment( ENV = os.environ , tools=['gfortran','gnulink'])
...
```

Does that work?